# The Fourier transform of the Bartlett (triangular) window

Tags: trigonometry, summation, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand how to obtain the Fourier transform of the Bartlett (triangular) window. The Bartlett window is defined as
$$
w_B(k)=\begin{cases}\frac{N-|k|}N,& |k|\le N;\\0,&|k|>N.\end{cases}
$$
The Fourier transform of the Bartlett window is then given by $
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}$.

Using the expression of the Bartlett window and the fact that $e^{jk\omega}+e^{-jk\omega}=2\cos(k\omega)$,
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{N-k}N\cos(k\omega).
$$
Since
$$
\sum_{k=0}^N\cos(k\omega)
 =\frac12+\frac{\sin((N+1/2)\omega)}{2\sin(\omega/2)},
$$
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^Nk\cos(k\omega)
 =\frac{(N+1)\sin((N+1/2)\omega)}{2\sin(\omega/2)}-\frac{1-\cos((N+1)\omega)}{4\sin^2(\omega/2)}
$$
and
$$
\frac{1-\cos((N+1)\omega)}2
 =\sin^2((N+1)\omega/2),
$$
we obtain
$$
\tag{#}
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}=\frac1N\biggl[\frac{\sin^2(N\omega/2+\omega/2)}{\sin^2(\omega/2)}-\frac{\sin(N\omega+\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\biggr].
$$
However, the answer should be
$$
\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}=\frac1N\biggl[\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\biggr]^2.
$$
How can we obtain the answer from $(\#)$? Is there a simpler way to obtain the Fourier transform of the Bartlett window?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's not definitive, but one way to test if the two answers are the same is to examine the behavior as $\omega\to 0$. They both appear to converge to $N$ in this limit, so that at least makes the desired equivalence plausible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired equality is $$\frac1N\biggl[\frac{\sin^2(N\omega/2+\omega/2)}{\sin^2(\omega/2)}-\frac{\sin(N\omega+\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\biggr]=\frac1N\biggl[\frac{\sin(N\omega/2)}{\sin(\omega/2)}\biggr]^2,$$ which upon multiplying both sides by $N\sin(\omega/2)^2$ and rearranging a bit simplifies to

$$\sin(\omega/2)\sin(N\omega+\omega/2)=\sin^2(N\omega/2+\omega/2)-\sin(N\omega/2)^2.$$
But if we recall the product-to-sum trigonometric formulas, we can write the LHS as $$\frac{1}{2}\biggl[\cos(N\omega) -\cos(N\omega+\omega) \biggr],$$ which we recognize as the RHS upon two applications of the double-angle formula $\cos 2\theta=1-2\sin^2\theta$. Hence the announced equality is shown.