# Doubt on Fourier Transform of Barlett window

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I saw this solution to the Bartlett window but I have a doubt on the step where the sum was transformed to the cosine.

I am trying to understand how was this done.

[Fourier Transform Batlett window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFexv.png)

Here it is the whole page of the solution.

[The Fourier transform of the Bartlett (triangular) window](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849012/the-fourier-transform-of-the-bartlett-triangular-window)

Thank you.

Comment: Euler's formula for complex exponentials implies sine and cosine are expressible as combinations of conjugate complex exponentials.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. I understand how the cosine is represented in its complex form, but not how the change was made in the sum of the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: For $k=1,\cdots,N$ you pair summand with index $k$ to the summand with $-k$ and combine them into a cosine. That is, for $1\le k\le N$ adding $w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}$ to $w_B(-k)e^{ik\omega}$ yields $\frac{N-k}{N}\cdot2\cos(k\omega)$.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you have written to me but It is not clear to me. Could you be so kind to help me with any book reference to understand better, please?

Comment: This doesn't need a book reference. Do you get how $$ w_B(k)e^{-ik\omega}+w_B(-k)e^{ik\omega}=\frac{N-k}{N}\cdot2\cos(k\omega) $$ given that $1\le k\le N$? First off, both coefficients $w_B(k)$ and $w_B(-k)$ are equal to $\frac{N-k}{N}$. Secondly, if I read you correctly you've already said you understand $e^{-ik\omega}+e^{ik\omega}$ equals $2\cos(k\omega)$. And this is relevant because your sum only has nonzero terms with $-N\le k\le N$, and further you can add the term with a positive $k$ to the corresponding term with $-k$ like I said. Please be specific about what is not clear to you

Comment: e.g. for $N=2$ the sum is $$w_B(-2)e^{2i\omega}+w_B(-1)e^{i\omega}+w_B(0)+w_B(1)e^{-i\omega}+w_B(2)e^{-2i\omega}$$ $$=w_B(0)+w_B(1)(e^{i\omega}+e^{-i\omega})+w_B(2)(e^{2i\omega}+e^{-2i\omega})$$ $$=1+\frac{2-1}{2}(2\cos \omega)+\frac{2-2}{2}(2\cos 2\omega)$$

Comment: So is this the way the entire sum from $-\infty$ to  $\infty$ is represented ? $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}\ w_{B}(k)e^{-jkw}=\sum_{k=-N}^{-1}\frac{N-k}{N}e^{-jkw}+1+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{N-k}{N}e^{-jkw}$  And $\ w_{B}(-k)e^{jkw} $is the value that corresponds to the negative part of the sum, right?

Comment: Almost, you need $\frac{N-|k|}{N}$ in the sum from $k=-N$ to $-1$. Then when you substitute (turn that sum into a sum from $1$ to $N$) the $|k|$ can be replaced by $k$.

Comment: To sum up $\sum_{k=-N}^{-1}\frac{N-|k|}{N}e^{-jkw}$ it's the same as $\ w_{B}(-k)e^{jkw}$ because of the absolute value of $k$, Right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your support today, you have saved me.